# Process/work flow in Java

Tags: java

I've got a specific project that I need to undertake and I would like some guidance from the masters before I take my first step.

We have a number of applications that receives input from some external sources (i.e. file, XML-RPC, web-service, etc), then processes it in some way, applying rules to it, communicating with other external systems (possibly), accessing a database (maybe) and then sending back a response.  We are maintaining different versions of the same application to cater for all the small differences between our clients. (Yes, yes, I know. It's terrible, that's why I want to fix it...)

The idea I am playing with is to have a component based architecture where different components can be wired together through configuration and the flow of information is governed through business rules.  It must, in essence, be possible to give each client a copy of the program with a different set of configuration.  I am even dreaming of a GUI-based application where a system can be wired together in a VB-style drag and drop fashion.

Now, the above sounds definitely like something that has been done before... and I do not want to reinvent the wheel.  The problem is that the above has to be able to handle high volumes of real-time transactions, so I am not sure whether something like BPEL will be the right choice.

Any recommendations before I go and make the wheel rounder?

Comment: It seems you are looking for some ETL tools; search for talend or apatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a very simple XML dialect for your application. Keep element-types to a minimum, and use `class="my.class.name'` attributes to build the correct class-instances at run-time. This makes it easy to have, say, a  element with 3 implementations (for instance
`<source class="my.package.XmlRpc">`, `<source class="my.package.LocalFile">` and `<source class="my.package.WebService">`). Each element-type, once instantiated, should read its XML contents to find any additional data it needs to configure itself correctly.

There are many easy-to-use XML parsing libraries (I recommend JDom), and there is a lot of tool support for XML viewing and editing. XML is easy to document, work with, and wrap into GUIs.

So: each component gets an element-type, and their specific implementation-dependent configurations are buried inside the elements. If you have simple wiring (specific component instances are only used in a single place), you can get away with inclusion. If you have complex wiring (you need to reuse component instances in several places; for instance, you want to re-use filters or compute intermediate results), first you define the component instances, and then you build the wiring out of references to these instances.

I am essentially advocating something like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) build-files, and for keeping things as simple as possible.

Comment: This is what I was thinking... and adding annotations for the input/output flow between classes.  However, I was hoping that there is something tried and tested out there already. (but +1 just because I really really would actually like to DIY this and you confirmed it :))

Comment: If you know a bit of XML and reflection, then I can guarantee that this will be a lot quicker than trying to find a one-size-fits-all solution and adapting it to work with your problem.

Comment: I am quite familiar with both... familiar enough to know its evil dark side.  I would probably look at something like Guice to do the object creation for me rather than introspection.

Comment: Not so dark; classForName(element.attribute("class")).newInstance() + result.configure(element) seems straightforward enough. Also, Guice is intended for compile-time, not run-time, bindings. How would you apply it to this case? injector.getInstance(classForName(element.attribute("class")))? What does that buy you?

Comment: I'll go with this approach.  It will give us the speed we need and I can make it elegant and extensible with the right libraries and best practises.  Thanks for the insight.